# How do I detect if the scoreboard value has changed?

Tags: minecraft-commands

What I'm going to do is detect if **stat.useItem.minecraft.golden_apple**'s value has **changed**.

How do I detect the change?

Comment: Flagging question as unclear because it does not specify which edition is being played.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `score_<scoreName>_min=1` in the selector, then I'd zero the score at the end of the commandblock chain using something like this: `scoreboard players set @a <scoreName> 0`

Ex. I want to use `/execute` on the person who ate the golden apple. so I'll use these commands: (in this order)

```
/execute @a[score_<scoreName>_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /...
/scoreboard players set @a <scoreName> 0
```

this will make it so the `/execute` will run once for each apple eaten.

Hopefully this helped

Comment: 1.13 syntax:`scores={scoreName=1..}`

Comment: @ppperry I'm not familiar with 1.13, I should get on that